# QGIS 3.10 send incorrect ArcGIS MapServer requests (pkk.rosreestr.ru)

Tags: arcgis-server, qgis-3, web-service, map-service

I am trying to add a web service (ArcGIS MapServer) in QGIS 3.10 here is the url:

```
https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer/
```

I see a list of layers, but QGIS gives the following error:

> Network error: Error transferring
>
> https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer/export?bbox=8097219.581788,8629436.355556,8242578.042442,8741170.443531&size=977,751&format=PNG32&layers=show:33&transparent=true&f=image
>   - server replied: Bad Request

Through the browser, I examined the requests that are sent when viewing the original site. I noticed that QGIS requests are different from requests received through the browser.

Requests sent through the **browser** (**successful**):

```
https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer/export?layers=show%3A&dpi=96&format=PNG32&bbox=8061966.247258484%2C8688138.383019326%2C8140237.764222398%2C8766409.899983242&bboxSR=102100&imageSR=102100&size=1024%2C1024&transparent=true&f=image
```

**1. Is it true that QGIS 3.10 does not work correctly with ArcGIS web services (MapServer)?**

**2. How to fix this behavior?**

Comment: Is https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/ the actual address of an ArcGIS Map Server?  error comes from a Varnish cache server

Comment: @nmtoken I'm not sure, but when I send a request in response, I get an image: https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer/export?layers=show%3A&dpi=96&format=PNG32&bbox=8061966.247258484%2C8688138.383019326%2C8140237.764222398%2C8766409.899983242&bboxSR=102100&imageSR=102100&size=1024%2C1024&transparent=true&f=image

Comment: In your example working URL you have `bboxSR=102100&imageSR=102100&` which don't appear in the non-working URL.  If QGIS thinks these are defaulted, but your server requires them, that might be a problem

Comment: @nmtoken There is a way to manually edit QGIS layer to add this part of request?

Comment: Not that I can see, you can't append them to the service URL (as might with a WMS or WFS) because  `https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer` is not the full stem of the request.

Comment: whether that means that `QGIS 3.10 does not work correctly with ArcGIS web services` will depend on what the ArcGIS web service specification says.

Comment: QGIS works for me with another ArcGIS MapServer but unfortunately that is not open for testing. It may be that pkk5.rosreestr.ru has some special rules in the proxy which block the requests made by QGIS. bboxSR and imageSR are not required, try https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/BordersGKN/MapServer/export?layers=show%3A&format=PNG32&bbox=8061966.247258484%2C8688138.383019326%2C8140237.764222398%2C8766409.899983242&size=1024%2C1024&transparent=true&f=image

Comment: @ComradeChe any update on this? Did you manage to open PKK in QGIS? I just found that there is pkk6 rest service appear https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/PKK6/Cadastre/MapServer

Comment: @Anatolii Nope still the same: `Network error: Error transferring https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/PKK6/Cadastre/MapServer/export?bbox=8166075.735344,8682845.427505,8168947.807177,8684853.738442&size=1075,751&format=PNG32&layers=show:&transparent=true&f=image - server replied: Forbidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after comments are in...

> Is it true that QGIS 3.10 does not work correctly with ArcGIS web services (MapServer)?

No, it's not true.

Your example service is expecting the `bboxSR` and `imageSR` parameters, but they are not required.

> How to fix this behavior?

The service (not QGIS) has to be modified to change it's expectation for non-required parameters.